# Apply asterisk extension expression matching in a python script

Tags: python, pattern-matching, asterisk

I would like to emulate asterisk extension matching in python. For example:

```
3494ZXXXXXX
```

Would match:

```
34941000000
```

But not match:

```
34940000000
```

I would like to support any matching operator provided by asterisk. I do not have an asterisk available, so no AMI can be used. So what I need is a way to implement this function:

```
def asterisk_extension_match(extension, pattern):
    '''Returns True if the extension matches the pattern, 
       according to the asterisk extension matching rules'''
    # Compute matches
    return matches
```

Is there any library implementing this pattern matching, or do I have to emulate it using regexes or similar? Do I need to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using regex by replacing **`xzn`**.
try some thing like this:

```
import re
def asterisk_extension_match(extension, pattern):
    '''Returns True if the extension matches the pattern,
       according to the asterisk extension matching rules'''
    pattern = re.sub(r'x', '[0-9]', pattern, flags=re.I)
    pattern = re.sub(r'z', '[1-9]', pattern, flags=re.I)
    pattern = re.sub(r'n', '[2-9]', pattern, flags=re.I)
    match = re.match(pattern, extension)        
    if match:
        return match.group()
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Not sure if this covers all possible asterisk matching patterns, but I will try it. I have also plans to provide a matching table, and pre-compile the regexes, and this approach will make it possible.